# c# How do deserialize json containing list of date

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I use external api to retrieve IOT data.
In the payload i get such data like below

```json
{
  "tenantId": "62b8c3a9d7b7c57a8d78c5b16fb4",
  "tenantName": "TEST IOT",
  "statisticsPerDay": {
    "2023-08-07": {
      "lora": {
        "counters": {
          "virtualMsgIn": 34,
          "numberOfSources": 1,
          "msgIn": 34,
          "bytesIn": 1428
        },
      },
    },
    "2023-08-08": {
      "lora": {
        "counters": {
          "virtualMsgIn": 22,
          "numberOfSources": 1,
          "msgIn": 22,
          "bytesIn": 924
        },
      },
    },
    "2023-08-05": {
      "lora": {
        "counters": {
          "virtualMsgIn": 13,
          "numberOfSources": 1,
          "msgIn": 13,
          "bytesIn": 546
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

My problem is how to deserialize using c# `statisticsPerDay` object that contain date as property name.

I've tried

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceStates>(data);
```

and my `DeviceStates` Class

```
public class DeviceStates
{
    [JsonProperty("tenantId")]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tenantName")]
    public string TenantName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("statisticsPerDay")]
    public StatisticsPerDay StatisticsPerDay { get; set; }

}

public class StatisticsPerDay
{

    [JsonProperty("lora")]
    public Lora Lora { get; set; }
}
```

But the `StatisticsPerDay` list is not deserialized I get `null`.

Comment: Use this https://json2csharp.com/ or other service to translate JSON to c# objects

Comment: statisticsPerDay should be Dictionary. example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/t1Jrvj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StatisticsPerDay` should be a `Dictionary`, with the day as key and the value an object (I called it `DayStatistic`) that contains your `Lora` property.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Converters;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {           
        string json = "{\n    \"tenantId\": \"62b8c3a9d7b7c57a8d78c5b16fb4\",\n    \"tenantName\": \"TEST IOT\",\n    \"statisticsPerDay\": {\n      \"2023-08-07\": {\n        \"lora\": {\n          \"counters\": {\n            \"virtualMsgIn\": 34,\n            \"numberOfSources\": 1,\n            \"msgIn\": 34,\n            \"bytesIn\": 1428\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      \"2023-08-08\": {\n        \"lora\": {\n          \"counters\": {\n            \"virtualMsgIn\": 22,\n            \"numberOfSources\": 1,\n            \"msgIn\": 22,\n            \"bytesIn\": 924\n          }\n        }\n      },\n      \"2023-08-05\": {\n        \"lora\": {\n          \"counters\": {\n            \"virtualMsgIn\": 13,\n            \"numberOfSources\": 1,\n            \"msgIn\": 13,\n            \"bytesIn\": 546\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }";
        DeviceStates state = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceStates>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state));
    }
}

public class DeviceStates
{
    public string TenantId { get; set; }

    public string TenantName { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, DayStatistic> StatisticsPerDay { get; set; }
}

public class DayStatistic
{
    public Lora Lora { get; set; }
}

public class Lora
{
    public Counters Counters { get; set; }
}

public class Counters
{
    public int VirtualMsgIn { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfSources { get; set; }

    public int MsgIn { get; set; }

    public int BytesIn { get; set; }
}
```